# Xamarin Databinding issue with datatemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, data-binding

Ok, I am a newbie in Xamarin and am struggling a bit with this. I am trying to create a page with a carousel of "pages" or "cards". It is actually working just fine, but I am not able to get the dynamic data (name, schoolClass and course) published inside?!

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
ObservableCollection<Details> collection = new ObservableCollection<Details>();

collection.Add(new Details { name = "Peter Hanson", schoolClass = "4. klasse", course = "Math" });
collection.Add(new Details { name = "Tom Jerk", schoolClass = "7. klasse", course = "Geography" });
collection.Add(new Details { name = "Caroline Jump", schoolClass = "1. klasse", course = "English" });

// Carousel pages template
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate(() =>
{

    var stacksample = new StackLayout()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        BackgroundColor = Color.White
    };

    stacksample.Children.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = "{Binding name}",
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    });

    stacksample.Children.Add(new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromResource("md.Images.default.png",
        typeof(EmbeddedImage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    });

    stacksample.Children.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = "{Binding schoolClass}",
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Style = Headline
    });

    stacksample.Children.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = "{Binding course}",
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        Margin = new Thickness(0, -8, 0, 0),
        Style = SubStyle
    });

    return stacksample;

});

carousel.ItemTemplate = template;
carousel.PositionSelected += pageChanged;
carousel.ItemsSource = collection;
```

I hope someone can help or guide me in the right direction and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: `Text = "{Binding name}"` I do not think this binding will work. Something is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I know... But not sure how to approach this :-/

Comment: @GaurangDave - That solved it... Thanks for your guidance ;-)